# Remove error messages at the top of bamboo

Tags: bamboo

I set up a bamboo on a server.
Everytime I open it lots of errors are shown on top of the page and I have to scroll down very far down to get to the actual application.

I didn't notice anything not working yet.

Therefore I want to ignore this for now and hide it.
[image]

Is there a property that I can change to hide these errors - if so, how do I change it?